# PHP mail function doesn't return the message

Tags: php, html

I seem to have encountered a problem within my code, and I am not sure if it's the PHP mailer causing it or me (most likely me) but let me spill it out.

I have a form which the values entered need to be send to the email.

```
<form method="post" action="index.php" />
                        <fieldset>
                            <input id="name" name="naam" type="text" value="" class="span4" placeholder="Naam" required/>
                            <input id="email" name="email" type="text" value="" class="span4" placeholder="Emailadres" required/>
                            <input id="telnr" name="telnr" type="text" value="" class="span4" placeholder="Telefoon nummer" optional/>
                            <textarea class="input-xlarge span12" id="message" name="bericht" rows="9" placeholder="Bericht" required></textarea>
                            <div class="actions">
                                <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-succes btn-large">Versturen</button>
                            </div>                          
                        </fieldset>
                    </form>
```

This actually returns the page to itself and runs through a PHP block

```
                    <?php
                    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

                        // defenitie variabellen
                        $name = $_POST["naam"];
                        $from = $_POST["email"];
                        $telnr = $_POST["telnr"];

                        if ($telnr = ''){
                            $telnr = "De gebruiker heeft geen telefoonnummer achtergelaten";    
                            }

                        echo $telnr;

                        $message = $_POST["bericht"];
                        $message = wordwrap($message, 70);  
                        $to = "info@something.com";
                        $subject = "Een gebruiker heeft een vraag of opmerking";
                        $body =  "<p>Een gebruiker heeft de volgende informatie achtergelaten:</p>";
                        $body .= "<table>";
                        $body .= "<tr>";
                        $body .= "<td>Van:</td><td> ".$name."</td>";
                        $body .= "</tr>";
                        $body .= "<tr>";
                        $body .= "<td>E-mail:</td><td> ".$from." </td></tr>";
                        $body .= "<tr>";
                        $body .= "<td>Telefoon:</td><td> ".$telnr."</td></tr>   ";
                        $body .= "</table>";
                        $body .= "<table>";
                        $body .= "<tr><td>".$message."</td></tr>";
                        $body .= "</table>";

                        echo $body;

                        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
                        $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
                        $headers .= "From: noreply@something.com";
                        // nu if else statement draaien
                         if ($name = ''){
                             echo '<p>U heeft geen naam ingevuld</p>';   
                         }else if($email = ''){
                             echo '<p>U heeft geen emailadres achter gelaten</p>';
                         }else if($body = ''){
                             echo '<p>U heeft geen bericht ingevuld niet ingevuld';
                         }
                         else {
                             if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
                                echo '<p>Uw bericht is verzonden.</p>';
                            } else {
                                echo '<p>Er is iets mis gegaan bij het verzenden van de data, probeer het opnieuw.</p>';
                            }
                        } 
                    }
                ?>
```

So as you maybe spot in the code, I bump into 2 problems. One is that the phone number is not being returned (i checked both when it comes in as a POST (I just did that, but it's blank) and once I run it through the if statement. Both stay blank.

Second part is the body. I echo'ed it out and it appears fine in a normal browser page, however when it doesn't get shot through in the email, thus the email stays blank. First I thought it was because I had added CSS inline, so I removed that, but the email stayed blank.

Can anybody spot my flaws, cause I am pretty positive i made a few errors here. I just been staring to long at it that I just dont see it. Most likely its really simple, yet I cant put my finger on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In all of your `if` statements, you are assigning values, not checking them.  You need to use `==` instead of `=`.

Comment: OMG, I feel so dumb. I feel like a moron, forgetting the assigning and is equal to ... And I saw I made an error with naming the variables too, in the else if statement fromt he email. Anyway, happy you could shed some light. Thanks! I ll accept it as awenser whenever I can.